# выводятся одни нули, результат сверху

Tags: java

```
x = 0.0     y = 0.0
x = 0.0     y = 0.0
x = 0.0     y = 0.0
x = 0.0     y = 0.0
x = 0.0     y = 0.0
x = 0.0     y = 0.0
x = 0.0     y = 0.0
```

Реализовать функциональность абстрактного класса AbstractArrayOfPoints, приведенного в примере, через использование двумерного массива вещественных чисел. Каждая строка массива должна соответствовать точке.

```
package r.t.y;
public class Point {
private double x, y;

public Point(double x, double y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public double getX() {
    return x;
}

public double getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setPoint(double x, double y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

}

 package r.t.y;

 public abstract class AbstractArrayOfPoints {

public abstract void setPoint(int i, int j, double x, double y);

public abstract double getX(int i, int j);


public abstract double getY(int i, int j);


public abstract int count();


public abstract void addPoint(double x, double y);


public abstract void removeLast();


public void sortByX() {
    boolean mustSort;
    do {
        mustSort = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < count() - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < count() - 1; j++) {
                if (getX(i, j) > getX(i + 1, j + 1)) {

                    double x = getX(i, j);
                    double y = getY(i, j);
                    setPoint(i, j, getX(i + 1, j + 1), getY(i + 1, j + 1));
                    setPoint(i + 1, j + 1, x, y);
                    mustSort = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    while (mustSort);
   }


   public String toString() {
    String s = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < count(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < count(); j++) {
            s += "x = " + getX(i, j) + " \ty = " + getY(i, j) + "\n";
        }
    }
    return s + "\n";
  }

     public void test() {
    addPoint(22, 45);
    addPoint(4, 11);
    addPoint(30, 5.5);
    addPoint(-2, 48);
    //sortByX();
    System.out.println(this);
}

}

 package r.t.y;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class ArrayWithTwoArrays extends AbstractArrayOfPoints {

private  double [][]axy = new double[4][4];
protected final static int cX = 0;
protected final static int cY = 0;
 // protected final static int DIRECTION = 0;
 @Override
  public void setPoint(int i, int j, double x, double y) {
    axy[i][cX] = x;
    axy[i][cY] = y;
}

@Override
public double getX(int i, int j) {
    return axy[i][cX];
}

@Override
public double getY(int i, int j) {
    return axy[i][cX];
}

@Override
public int count() {
    return axy.length; // Можна ay.length, вони однакові
}

   @Override
   public void addPoint(double x, double y) {
    double[][] axy1 = new double[axy.length + 1][axy.length+1];
    System.arraycopy(axy, 0, axy1, 0, axy.length);
    axy1[axy.length][axy.length] = getX(0,0);
    axy1[axy.length][axy.length] = getY(0,0);
    axy = axy1;
   // double[] ay1 = new double[ay.length + 1];
   // System.(ay, 0, ay1, 0, ay.length);
    //ay1[ay.length] = y;
    //ay = ay1;
 }

  @Override
  public void removeLast() {
    if (count() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    double[][] axy1 = new double[axy.length - 1][axy.length - 1];
    System.arraycopy(axy, 0, axy1, 0, axy1.length);
    axy = axy1;
   // double[] ay1 = new double[ay.length - 1];
    //System.arraycopy(ay, 0, ay1, 0, ay1.length);
    //ay = ay1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ArrayWithTwoArrays().test();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

поставьте брэйкпойнт в `r.t.y.ArrayWithTwoArrays.getX` на 17 строке (см стэктрейс) и запустите дебаг. думаю вы увидете, что массив `axy` пустой, а поэтому попытка получить его первый (т.е. 0-ой) элемент заканчивается эксепшном.

Answer (score 0):

```
private double [][] axy = new double[][]{};
```

Вот этой строчкой Вы создаёте массив с 0 элементов. Естественно, при попытке обратиться к элементам этого массива в методе setPoint Вы получаете ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException (выход индекса за пределы границ массива). Короче говоря, создавайте массив нужной размерности прежде чем в него что-то помещать, в Java массивы сами собой не растягиваются =)